# how did telegra.ph add cookie headers to enable edit article in different devices

Tags: cookies

I want edit https://telegra.ph/ article in my different devices.Now I want to copy the https://telegra.ph/ website cookie to my other device and enable the "Edit" button.But I found the request header contains cookie and the application tab did not contains any cookie.The request header contains cookie:

[image]

The application did not contains any cookie:

[image]

I found some tool to add Cookie field in my request,but failed,maybe the chrome browser could add any header except some system reserved header,so what should I do to make me could edit my telegra.ph article in different devices?Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download chrome [cookie inspector](http://www.bigbadgoose.com/cookie-inspector) plugin,and add your article cookie in.This plugin could add cookie key value pair when request to https://telegra.ph/ ,try to add your cookie to any device you want to edit the article.Pay attention you could keep you cookie carefully because anyone get the cookie could edit the article.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a plugin. Open https://edit.telegra.ph and edit cookie on the Application tab in the Chrome developer tools.
[image: Telegraph cookie editing]